# How to get element position relative to parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i change, so that y is set to zero?

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/2672/

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 50px;">
  <div id="dragThis">
    <ul>
      <li id="posX"></li>
      <li id="posY"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
  drag: function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    var xPos = position.left;
    var yPos = position.top;
    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#dragThis {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I've been changing "position" to "offset" and i have tried to change the CSS position. But i cannot figure out, how to get y, to count top from its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the x and y position of its container and deduct those values from the appropriate values.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfd4wb3c/).

Alternatively, give the draggable element's `position: absolute` and the parent `position: relative`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq6rL8k0/).

Comment: Thank you. I do not wana use math to get the position. But to change parent to relative, was what i was looking for!

Comment: @Mjukis Don't be afraid of some maths :D

Comment: It's complicated, because my real project has nestled div's.. so math will be very complex... :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for the parent and subtract it from the child like this:

```js
$('#dragThis').draggable({
  drag: function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    var xPos = position.left;
    var yPos = position.top;
    var xPosParent = $('#parent').offset().left;
    var yPosParent = $('#parent').offset().top;
    $('#posX').text('x: ' + (xPos - xPosParent));
    $('#posY').text('y: ' + (yPos - yPosParent));
  }
});
```

```css
    #dragThis {
      width: 6em;
      height: 6em;
      padding: 0.5em;
      border: 3px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 50px;">
  <div id="dragThis">
    <ul>
      <li id="posX"></li>
      <li id="posY"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to take the `x` value into account, otherwise in the example code with padding its hard against the edge with a value of `7` for the `x`.

Comment: Added x for the example ;)